# Floating text over text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a pull quote class that can be applied to any text. Usually this will be a short quote I want to float to the right. I would like the text in the body to come up to the set margin for each line in the floated pull quote.

[Goal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC5NA.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC5NA.jpg)

The problem I am running into is that the div or span is creating a rectangle around the floated text so the shorter lines in the pull quote have a lot of whitespace to the left.

What I'm getting example: [i.stack.imgur.com/bvJv2.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvJv2.jpg)

I want this text flow effect to work automatically which means I don't want to have to set each line's "width" automatically. I just want to apply a class to a div or span and have it achieve this look. I would also like to keep this HTML/CSS/CSS3. I can't easily apply JS to this since it's a closed CMS I'm dealing with.

Any tricks? Is this even possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Also... @Scotty your image bvJv2.jpg is not linked properly

Comment: @Paulie_D: I don't think this is a "why doesn't my code work" type question but rather a "how do I even approach this" conceptional question. I'm not sure if there's some CSS attribute out there that I don't know about. I cannot find anything about floating text over text but letting the text flow into the div.

Comment: @Age: I don't have enough reputation yet to pat multiple links, images, etc.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to is not possible, as far as I know, with text wrapping around other text.

It is, however, possible to wrap text around floated shapes. Take a look at the spec for [CSS shapes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-shapes-1/).

Maybe you can do something with a polygon to create the effect you're trying to accomplish; though, I suspect it will be a challenge since it is likely that the content of your quotes are dynamic.

Comment: I saw the floating shapes idea and it's on the table. However I would prefer to have a set CSS treatment for all pull quotes and not have to manually set a new shape for ever quote. This would be launched in a CMS theme and a lot of the users that would be deploying this wouldn't have the technical understanding to manually tweak the shapes.

Answer (score 1):

What about doing something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ToreanJoel/wfoezo0t/1/

Making a `h1` tag and put some spans inside them for each word/few words.

```
<h1>
  <span>"This is a</span>
  <span class="spacer"></span>
  <span>blockquote</span>
  <span class="spacer"></span>
  <span>to test"</span>
</h1>
```

---

Then for the css the following:

```
h1 {
    font-size:44px;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
h1 span{
    float:right;
    text-align: right;
    clear:both;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 14px;
}

.spacer {
    height: 10px;
}
.paragraph {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

---

Note im making the text around heading (`.paragraph` class) justified and that will give you  something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ToreanJoel/wfoezo0t/1/

remember its editible for your likeing good luck

Comment: I like this approach and I might have to go this route. It would be nice to not have to manually break apart the line, but I might not have a choice. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Always good to know it helped, let me know of any updates if you find another solution, I found the questions interesting